# How to precompose a layer in an After Effects script?

Tags: after-effects

How to precompose a layer with all the effects applied to it programmatically in an After Effects jsx script?

Let's say I have the composition and the layer I want to precompose:

```js
var myComp = app.project.activeItem;
var layers = myComp.selectedLayers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `precompose` function of a composition and pass down the layer indices that need to be procomposed:

This example would precompose the first layer of an active comp:

```js
{
  function MyScript(thisObj) {

    var myComp = app.project.activeItem
    var layers = myComp.selectedLayers

    var newComp = comp.layers.precompose(
      [1], 
      'Precomp_Name', 
      true);
    )
  }
  MyScript(this)
}
```